# column break versus page break ssrs

Tags: reporting-services, ssrs-2008, multiple-columns, page-break

I'm trying to write a report that reports based on the time of day (shift) and the day itself.  I'm using three columns in the report, which I set in the reports properties without issue.

The issue that I am encountering is that after every day, and every shift, I must start a new page.  So I put in a page break after each event, but all that I get is a column break.

How can this be circumvented to get an actual page break and not a column break?  Why would they make it a column break to begin with?

I am using Visual Studio 2008.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You should look into using the Lists container in SSRS, it allows you to easily group by fields of your choice and then break in between each group. It is a common choice for reports that require one page per group, with data presented for each group. Inside your list container you'll be able to add a matrix or table to represent your data, in addition to any text boxes or other objects you need displayed on a per group basis. https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd239330.aspx

Comment: Hi TPhe; grouping isn't my issue, its that SSRS is putting COLUMN breaks when I ask for a PAGE break.

That is, unless Lists provide some way of mitigating this, which from your link, it does not appear to do so.

Comment: There are numerous places in SSRS that you can designate a page break. Where did you select the page break - in the properties of the table, or in the properties of the group?

Comment: Also, it would help to clarify what you mean by a column break - maybe with a screenshot? If the issue is that some columns are getting bumped on to the next page, it would be a good idea to check that the width of your table/body is not more that the page width minus the margins designated in your report properties, and that you have the properties of the text boxes set so that they cannot expand horizontally.

Comment: Sure; I'll try with words, and then try to get a good screen shot of what is happening.

What is happening is I have a report with three columns.  Not data columns, but display columns.  After I finish with data for a unique day, I want to start a new page.  So, in the grouping for the day, I have a page break set to exist between each group.

What happens, is instead of starting a brand new page, it starts a new display column.  So if I have data filling just the first display column for Day #1, Day #2 starts in display Column 2 --on the same page--, instead of a brand new page.

Comment: Interesting, I've never made a report with distinct display columns like that. I think my recommendation is still to utilize the list - I would create a list container and put all three of the display columns inside it, then define groups and page breaks at the list level. This effectively restricts the data that gets to your columns - the list will break on a per page basis, and the columns will 'run out' of data for each group. I don't think it would be possible for just one column to break and then have the next group's data start on the next column when the list is "feeding" the data.